# Update local List with newly added object in breeze

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am new to Breeze and i am trying to build a sample application using Breeze Angular with WebApi. I am facing an issue i need to update the local Array (Angular) with newly added object **SaveResult**.
Server Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return  context.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
```

Client Code

```
$scope.AddNewProduct = function () {
       if ($scope.Product !== null) {
        datacontext.addNew($scope.Product, function (newProduct) {
            $scope.Products.unshift(newProduct);
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
};
```

Its not working. Its updating the UI with empty values

I have three methods in my WebApi as per breeze demo application.

```
namespace AngularWebApi.ApiControllers
{
[BreezeController]
public class ProductsBreezeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ProductRepository context;

    public ProductsBreezeController()
    {
        context = new ProductRepository();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return context.Metadata();
    }

    //// GET api/productsbreeze
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return context.TodoLists;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return  context.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
}

public class ProductRepository : EFContextProvider<SampleEntities>
{
    public DbQuery<Product> TodoLists
    {
        get { return Context.Products; }
    }
}
```

}

Now **GetAllProducts** returns this as single entity

```
$$hashKey: "004"
_backingStore: Object
entityAspect: ctor
maxUnits: (...)
productId: (...)
productName: (...)
__proto__: Object
```

but SaveChanges method returns

```
_backingStore: Object
entityAspect: ctor
maxUnits: (...)
productId: (...)
productName: (...)
__proto__: Object
```

missing **$$hashKey: "004"** property from SaveChanges method. I dont know what to do in that context.

Comment: Check whether the object returned in `newProduct` as the same properties as the other objects binded to UI.

Comment: I have updated the question to more clarification about the issue

Comment: `$$hashKey` is not coming from server, but angularjs adds it when doing ng-repeat. When you say UI has empty values, is it only for the new row? Is it at the beginning or end?

Comment: so what should be there to add new object in Angular list

Comment: please show us your `datracontext.addNew` method. Why does it have a callback instead of using promises? Why are you calling $apply? Have you looked at the [Todo Angular sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-angular) for ideas?